# Python: Find the list element that is contained least times in another list

Tags: python, list

So I have a list of possible elments:

```
elems = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Then I have another list of random items chosen from the first list.
Something like (for example):

```
items = ['a', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'd']
```

What is the Pythonic way to find out which element in `elems` is contained least often in `items`?
In this example it is `'b'`, because that's not contained in `items` at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short**

```
print(min(elems, key=items.count)) # b
```

**Relatively short and efficient** (only use it if you're sure there're **no** duplicates in `elems`)

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(items + elems)
print(c.most_common()[-1][0]) # b
```

**Just efficient**

```
d = {x: 0 for x in elems} 
for x in items:
    d[x] += 1

print(min(d, key=d.get)) # b
```

**Another "just efficient"**

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int) 
for x in items:
    d[x] += 1

print(min(elems, key=d.__getitem__)) 
# or print(min(elems, key=lambda x: d[x])) - gives same result
```

Comment: computational complexity is len(elems)*len(items), it can be done in linear-logarithmic time

Comment: you can use `min(d, key=d.get)` for the short

Comment: Adding items and elems is clever, although it took me a moment's thought to make sure that it was correct.  Not sure if that's a good thing or a bad thing.

Comment: I think you are really over-using lambdas.  Instead of `min(elems, key=lambda x: items.count(x))`, just `min(elems, key=items.count)`.  Instead of `min(elems, key=lambda x: d[x])`, just `min(elems, key=d.get)`.  Lambdas suck in python.

Comment: OK, you could use `d.__getitem__` instead of the lambda if you wanted to have the 0 from defaultdict.  But `None` is guaranteed to compare less than any integer in python2, so it will still work anyway.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that - what's wrong with `d.__getitem__`?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> elems = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> items = ['a', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'd']
>>> c = Counter(dict.fromkeys(elems, 0))
>>> c.update(Counter(items))
>>> c
Counter({'a': 3, 'c': 2, 'd': 1, 'b': 0})
>>> min(c, key=c.get)
'b'
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is to make a dictionary with counts in it:

```
aDict = { k:0 for k in elems }
for x in items: 
  if x not in aDict: aDict[x] = 0 
  aDict[x] += 1 

print min(aDict, key=aDict.get)
```